# control what the enter key does in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-controls, enter

I have a `RichTextBox` that i am searching text in and I want to be able to control what the enter key does when text is selected. I am able to use this if test below to call the method that I want, but my issue is after the method gets hit when the enter key is pressed it then moves the text to the second line and I want to be able to stop this from happening when the text is highlighted.

I test to check if the text is selected when enter is pressed.

```
if (IsTextSelected == true)
{
   btnSearch_Click(sender, null);
}
```

Comment: Which event handler are you using to check key presses? I believe if you use `PreviewKeyUp`, you can do your search and then set `e.Handled = true` on the event args, which should stop the control from further processing the key press.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to the `PreviewKeyDown` event like:

```
  <RichTextBox PreviewKeyDown="RichTextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

and in the handler:

```
private void RichTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
       // DO YOUR WORK HERE and then set e.Handled to true on condition if you want to stop going to next line//

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```